# why does my parrot os not showing the normal login UI?

Tags: parrotsec

well i don't know what i did, but my parrotOS login UI just changed after restarting

it looks like this now:
[image: PICTURE]

please help

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to add more details: (1) What did it look like before? (2) What did you change in the session before it turned out like this? (3) Can you still log in? ... etc. ...

Comment: Is the angle because of your photography, or is that the issue that's concerning you? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734905/edit) to explain. Do not reply (to anyone) in the comments here.